# How to update multiple rows at once from the View (ASP.NET - Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I've got a View which shows a table of Devices that are stored in my Database, the database is made using Code-First with Entity Framework Core. Now my goal is to update the EnableAlertsUpload boolean of multiple rows at the same time. As can be seen in the picture below.

[image]

Now when I run the code and press the update button the page will just refresh without updating the EnableAlertsUpload boolean. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, most explanations only tell ho to update a single value by ID but not multiple rows at the same time.

My code looks as follows:

**Controller**

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditList()
    {
        var devices = db.Devices;

        return View(devices);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditList(int id, [Bind("EnableAlertsUpload")] Devices[] devices)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (Devices dev in devices)
                {
                    db.Update(dev);
                }
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(IndexV2));
        }

        return View(devices);
    }
```

**EditList View**

```
@model IEnumerable<FrontlineAI.Models.Devices>

<h1>Devices</h1>

<form asp-action="EditList">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.objid)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.device)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.group)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.host)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EnableAlertsUpload)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.objid)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.device)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.group)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.host)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.EnableAlertsUpload)</td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button input type="submit" value="Edit">Update</button>
</form>
```

**Devices Model**

```
public partial class Devices
{
    [Key()]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int objid { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
    public string device { get; set; }
    public string host { get; set; }
    public bool EnableAlertsUpload { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you you did not successfully bind the data, you can try my following code.

**EditList View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Devices>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>Devices</h1>

<form asp-action="EditList">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.objid)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.device)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.group)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.host)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EnableAlertsUpload)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ToList()[i].objid)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ToList()[i].objid)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ToList()[i].device)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ToList()[i].device)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ToList()[i].group)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ToList()[i].group)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ToList()[i].host)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ToList()[i].host)
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ToList()[i].EnableAlertsUpload)</td>
                </tr>
                }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button input type="submit" value="Edit">Update</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditList(int id, List<Devices> devices)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (Devices dev in devices)
                {
                    _context.Update(dev);
                }
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        }
       return RedirectToAction(nameof(EditList));
    }
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for taking the time to answers my question and even record it. I've been stuck on this problem for a whole day. It's weird it won't work with the foreach loop. I have about 2000 records to load and it takes about 10 seconds to load the page using the for loop. But I'm glad you've got it to work, thanks again!